# Unable to install "Turicreate" on my Windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, turi-create

I am new to Python and I am trying to build a recommendation engine by following a tutorial. The tutorials asks me to install turicreate, I am running Spyder 3.3.0 (Python version 3.5) on Anaconda.

WHAT I TRIED - 
I sought help from various SO questions as well as github, but none helped. I tried using "pip" and it gave the following error-

> Failed building wheel for turicreate
>     Running setup.py clean for turicreate
>   Failed to build turicreate

Tried "conda install ", but error again.

> Solving environment: failed 
>   PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:- turicreate

My "pip" and "conda" and "anaconda" are up to date. I tried creating a virtual environment and then installing "turicreate", but didn't help. I visited the anaconda.org website which had "conda install -c derickl turicreate", I tried, which gave the following error.

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:- turicreate

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to the [page](https://pypi.org/project/turicreate/#files) of the `turicreate` package on the Python repository index (PyPI), you will find that it can only be installed natively on Linux and macOS.

The only way to use it on Windows is through the [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), and for that you need to install Anaconda or Python on it (I think, I've never used WSL).

Comment: It is a real pain I will say. Use a LINUX distro natively.

Comment: I'm using it with WSL and it is very easy to setup.  Install Ubuntu from the store, open shell, install Anaconda or Miniconda or virtualenv, install turicreate.  What's a little more complicated is if you want to use GPU acceleration.  For that (as of today) you need to get a prerelease Windows 10 via Insider program, upgrade your NVidia driver, set 2.0 as the default WSL, and run Windows update a couple of times.  The experience of using turicreate on WSL with Jupyter notebooks running in your desktop browser is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem already solved :). But I had a similar problem and I solved it using a different way. I am posting it because I think it will help someone in the future. First, I want to say, If you are following something like a Video tutorial as mentioned in the question above, use that method. Thanks!

1. First Goto this [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#create=true&language=python2) URL. It will navigate you to colab with python version 2.
2. My runtime settings as follows. Runtime type: python 2 | Hardware accelerator:
   TPU
3. Then run `!pip install turicreate` and after finishing installation it will say `You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions`.After restart your runtime you will able to use turicreate with colab.

I hope it will help someone!