# Error trying to install Turicreate in Anaconda with Python 3.5 under Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, turi-create

I am trying to install Turicreate using Anaconda and Python 3.5 in Windows 10 using the following command:

```
pip install -U turicreate
```

I have followed the exact steps on the official page and still getting this error after executing the previous command:

```
    Collecting turicreate
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/96/19/44edfc07bd1b03596578ff02d9727b83c2ae50ee969ce2ab23724009d9ff/turicreate-5.7.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\user\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5e3jtboa\\turicreate\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5e3jtboa\\turicreate\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e3jtboa\turicreate\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5e3jtboa\turicreate\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5e3jtboa\\turicreate\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install "Turicreate" on my Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125459/unable-to-install-turicreate-on-my-windows-10). Specifically, Windows support is limited to WSL.

Comment: My problem is different than the one you referred to. I tried many solutions and none of them worked for me .

Comment: while that may be true, the output shown here is clearly running under Windows, not WSL and that is not supported as is answered in the other question. Try installing WSL and if you have problems installing Turicreate in that then you should ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I thought that Anaconda works as a WSL but I was wrong. I installed WSL Ubuntu 16 and inside it I installed the library and it works well. [Sorry for the late response but my laptop was not working and I had it fixed recently]